# change the color of a vertex in a vertex shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, vertex-shader

Is it possible to set the color of a single vertex using a GLSL vertex shader program, in the same way that gl_Position changes the position of a vertex ?

Comment: Which OpenGL version do you use? *Always* remember to explain this.

Comment: GL_ARB_shading_language_100 extension

Comment: The OpenGL version, not the shader version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For versions of GLSL prior version 1.30, you want to write to the `gl_FrontColor` or `gl_BackColor` built-ins, which are varyings accessible in the vertex shader. Read about varyings in the GLSL 1.10 specification (http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.Full.1.10.59.pdf) to learn more about them, or the GL_ARB_vertex_shader extension specification.

`gl_FrontColor` and `gl_BackColor` are 4D RGBA vectors which take normalized floating point scalars.

But this will set *all* the vertices to red, not just one vertex. This is because the same vertex shader is run for all the vertices. If you want to set individual colours, use `glColorPointer` together with `glDrawArrays`, `glDrawElements`, `glDrawRangeElements` or `glMultiDrawElements`. The vertex color set by `glColorPointer` can be read as `gl_Color` in the vertex shader. `gl_Color` in the vertex shader is a per-vertex attribute.

To read the color you wrote in the vertex shader, in the fragment shader, read the built-in varying `gl_Color`. Finished fragments should be written to `gl_FragColor`.

Vertex shader example:

```
void main()
{
    gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
}
```

Fragment shader example:

```
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = gl_Color;
}
```

Also, to make the vertex shader set the varyings just like the OpenGL fixed-function pipeline, call the function ftransform().

```
void main()
{
    ftransform();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. BTW, it seems that the definition of the fragment shader (with at least gl_FragColor = glColor) is mandatory to when gl_FrontColor is used in a vertex shader.

Comment: err, gl_Position set in fragment shader ? glColor rather than gl_Color ? ftransform by itself, without setting to gl_Position ?

Comment: In the fragment shader, it should be: gl_FragColor = gl_Color; not gl_FragColor = glColor;

Comment: correction: it's gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix not gl_ModelviewProjectionMatrix (capitalized V) in the Vertex Shader and gl_Color not glColor in the Fragment Shader

Comment: Just want to thank you for this answer. It saved me a lot of time and performance!